# Bash script display results in a specific order or sequence

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, sed, cat

I've tried various solutions via sed awk and array manipulation ((in bash)), but have not found a solid way to make the following happen:

Let's say I have a file named `states.txt` containing:

```
Alabama
Alaska
Arizona
Arkansas
California
Colorado

and so-on and so forth
```

I want to cat `states.txt` and have the result be the first and second state, then the second and third state, then third and fourth, etc.

I also want to ignore the fact that the states are in alphabetical order (the actual file contents I am going for are not in such order).

The result should look like:

```
Alabama
Alaska

then

Alaska
Arizona

then

Arizona
Arkansas

then

Arkansas
California

then

California
Colorado

and so-on and so forth
```

Thank you for your time and patience on this one.  I appreciate any help offered.

Comment: Have you tried yourself to script it?

Comment: Are you just trying to duplicate all the lines except the first and the last? Are the spaces and `then` lines in the output relevant?

Comment: @ ColOfAbRiX : 

Sure have.  Various solutions / research via the web to find solutions in awk, sed, and array manipulation.  None had given me the output I was looking for.

@Etan -- the spaces and then `then` are not relevant.  It was just a separation of the output for ease of reading.

Comment: So then are you just trying to duplicate even non-first non-last line in the file? So that there are running pairs the whole way?

Comment: @Etan : I am trying to parse through a file that has a descriptor that is easily predicted and extracted, and then cat that file to output the results in between the first descriptor and then the second.  Then the contents of the file between the second and the third, and so-on and so-forth.

Comment: @AndyD'Arata People like you to give an example of what you have already tried.

Comment: That doesn't help explain the goal to me *at all*. Please give us **exact** input and **exact** output for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @EtanReisner I went ahead and edited the original question to reflect a fabrication of EXACTLY what I am trying to accomplish, and where I am hung up at.

Comment: @JID Thank you for your suggestion, full explanation is listed above.

Comment: What on earth does your newly updated question have to do with your original question??? Get rid of the new stuff above, mark one of the answers you got as "accepted" and start over with a new question that has just your real sample input AND the associated desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you said the spacing between pairs of lines in your "expected output" is actually not relevant:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{print p ORS $0} {p=$0}' file
Alabama
Alaska
Alaska
Arizona
Arizona
Arkansas
Arkansas
California
California
Colorado
```

Caveat - if your file only contains 1 line it will not be printed. Easy fix with an END section if needed for that case.

Comment: This is better than what i suggested +1

Answer (score 3):

I would use something like this, storing the previous line and printing it together with the next one:

```
awk 'NR==1 {prev=$0; next} {print prev, $0; prev=$0}'
```

So for example a sequence of `5` numbers will output:

```
$ seq 5 | awk 'NR==1 {prev=$0; next} {print prev, $0; prev=$0}'
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

Comment: Instead of the NR==1 block you could rewrite like `awk 'prev{print prev, $0}{prev=$0}' file` . Only suggesting because i don't like `next` :) .Doesn't look like prev could be `0` or `""` but obviously you know you could just change it to `prev~/./{blahdeblah}`

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
awk 'length(last){print last} {print; print ""; last=$0;}'
```

Or in normal shell:

```
last=""
while read line; do
 [ -n "$last" ] && printf "%s\n" "$last"
 printf "%s\n\n" "$line"
 last="$line"
done
```

These are both shown as pipes.  You could redirect input from a file if you want, of course.

Comment: Those would fail if a line was empty (assuming it doesn't need to be skipped). The shell script would also strip any indentation from the file and strip escape chars, e.g. `\t` -> `t` (in general do not use shell loops to manipulate text but if you have some reason to do it then always use `while IFS= read -r line` unless you have a specific reason not to and fully understand all the implications/caveats).

Comment: Good points.  I'll leave my answer as-is, because your comment is a good pointer for others who see it, and better answers already exist (notably, yours) to this question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=-1;
while IFS= read -r line; do
printf "%s\n" "$line"
((count++))
[[ $count == 1 ]] && printf "\n" && count=-1;
done <states.txt
```

Another solution:

```
IFS=$'\n'
arr=($(< file))
for ((i=0;i<${#arr[@]};i++)); do
[[ $((i%2)) -eq 0 && $i != 0 ]] && printf "\n"
printf "%s\n" "${arr[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: See the comments about using shell while loops under the very similar solution @ghoti posted earlier. Also, never use `printf "$line\n"` but use `printf '%s\n' "$line"` instead. Imagine the difference if `line` contained `%s` or some other `printf` formatting string.

Comment: Don't forget to set `IFS`. Also, in the 2nd solution you don't need `text`, you can just do `arr=( $(< file) )`

Comment: Remember `while IFS= read -r line` in the first one or you'll strip any indentation. Honestly though - just don't do this in shell, it's simply not what shell is for, which is why it's so tricky to write it robustly.